# want to add one text box and button and static field in the centre of the screen on an image using wxpython? help me out not to overlap and placement

Tags: python, wxpython

I am learning ui python and trying out wxpython for UI development (dont have UI exp either). I have been able to create a frame with a panel, a button and a text input box. I want to bring all these to center of the screen where they look properly, so that i can implement the rest of the functionality. currently they are overlapping

```
class KartScan(wx.Panel):
        """ create a panel with a canvas to draw on"""
        def __init__(self, parent):
            wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY)
            # pick a .jpg, .png, .gif, or .bmp wallpaper image file you
            # have in the working folder or give full path
            image_file = 'index.png'
            self.bmp = wx.Bitmap(image_file)
            # this 50ms delay is needed to allow image loading first
            # may have to increase delay for very large images
            wx.FutureCall(50, self.make_canvas)
            # react to a resize event and redraw image
            wx.EVT_SIZE(self, self.make_canvas)
            # now put a button on the panel, on top of the wallpaper
            sizer = wx.GridBagSizer()

            self.entry = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, value=u"Enter Waybill No.")
            sizer.Add(self.entry, (0, 0), (1, 1), wx.EXPAND)
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.OnPressEnter, self.entry)

            button = wx.Button(self, -1, label="Add or Compare")
            sizer.Add(button, (0, 1))
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButtonClick, button)

            self.label = wx.StaticText(self, -1, label=u'This App is used !')
            self.label.SetBackgroundColour(wx.WHITE)
            self.label.SetForegroundColour(wx.BLUE)
            sizer.Add(self.label, (1, 0), (1, 2), wx.EXPAND)

            sizer.AddGrowableCol(0)
            self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
            self.SetSizeHints(-1, self.GetSize().y, -1, self.GetSize().y)
            self.entry.SetFocus()
            self.entry.SetSelection(-1, -1)
            self.Show(True)

        def make_canvas(self, event=None):
            # create the paint canvas
            dc = wx.ClientDC(self)
            # forms a wall-papered background
            # formed from repeating image tiles
            brush_bmp = wx.BrushFromBitmap(self.bmp)
            dc.SetBrush(brush_bmp)
            # draw a rectangle to fill the canvas area
            w, h = self.GetClientSize()
            dc.DrawRectangle(0, 0, w, h)

        def OnButtonClick(self, event):
            self.label.SetLabel(self.entry.GetValue() + " You clicked the button !")
            self.entry.SetFocus()
            self.entry.SetSelection(-1, -1)
    on click events
        def OnPressEnter(self, event):
            self.label.SetLabel(self.entry.GetValue() + " You pressed enter !")
            self.entry.SetFocus()
            self.entry.SetSelection(-1, -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The sizers do their layout work in the window's `EVT_SIZE` event. Since you are intercepting that event for your own thing then the sizer will not have a chance to do its work unless you help it.

One way to do it would be to call `self.Layout()` in the size event handler. Another way would be to call `event.Skip()` which will tell wx that the event should continue to be processed after your handler has returned. That allows the window's default size handler to still get the event and do the layout, and possibly other things depending on the type of the window class.